# how to disable the previous activity when click on the next activity

Tags: android

I am having multiple activity in my program the flow of it is like `MainActivity`-`LoginActivity`-`NextLoginActivity` etc.,I am applying transparency theme  on each activity except main activity so I want when I click any activity it should show `MainActivity` in background rather than previous activity.

Comment: `finish()` the current Activity when you start the next one..?

Comment: I dont know why you would want to do that but if you still want to do every navigation finish your current activity before going to next activity and when you press back in your next manually open the previous one

Comment: write **finish();** after **startActivity(intent);**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give an id to the parent layout in each activity and handle clicks on it.

Something like:

```
LinearLayout LoginActivity = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_activity);
LoginActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity));
//If you want to close this one
//this.finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want result below?

You open app, app into these activity in order: `MainActivity -> LoginActivity -> OtherActivity`

And you want to `click a button` that in `OtherActivity`, you don't want to return the `LoginActivity` but `MainActivity`

If it is, you can do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In this line: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Activity will use the `Launch Mode` by `singleTask`.

If activity stack has MainActivity, it will finish other activity that on top of MainActivity, then return MainActivity.